# Logistic regression with rare events

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, rare-events

Could somebody provide some references on the application of logistic regression for modelling rare events?

So far I've come across three methods with the main references below:

1. Exact logistic regression ([paper](https://link-springer-com.ezproxy.lib.gla.ac.uk/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-23805-0_8))
2. Firth method ([paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.7273))
3. King and Langche approach ([paper](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/4125045/relogit%20rare%20events.pdf?s))

Comment: Ordinary maximum likelihood estimation for logistic regression parameters is intended to handle rare events.  More care needs to be taken for getting confidence limits and p-values, by using likelihood ratio test methods instead of Wald (standard error-based) methods.  What is your worry?

Comment: @FrankHarrell I was reading at [link](https://statisticalhorizons.com/logistic-regression-for-rare-events) that 'The problem is that maximum likelihood estimation of the logistic model is well-known to suffer from small-sample bias'. For rare events like the one I'm trying to model (<3%, around 39 cases) I'm worried that MLE  would be too biased because of the rarity of the event.

Comment: Paul Allison's comments are very useful and on point.  I just don't know whether the magnitude of the bias makes it worth doing anything about.  And note that if you used a Bayesian logistic model, everything is exact, and it doesn't require changing the model as "exact" logistic regression does in the frequentist setting.

Comment: dups: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306122/rare-events-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70981/rare-event-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100974/rare-event-logistic-regression-bias-correction, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307635/what-are-the-consequences-of-rare-events-in-logistic-regression