# Bias the classification in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, classification, loss-functions

I want to make my classifier prioritise finding true cases (1) even if that means that a lot of the false cases (0) are also classified as true.

Specifically I wish to find the weights to my features that gives at least 97 % of my true cases as true and as a small fraction as possible of my false cases as false.

What should I be looking for in a logistic regression setting? Of course I can just adjust the intercept but I assume that there must be some better way?

Comment: sometimes questions get overlooked, or take some time to get noticed. This is a very good question and I've upvoted it, but you might need to wait a few days for an answer

Comment: You have started off your project with multiple misconceptions.  See for example http://www.fharrell.com/2017/01/classification-vs-prediction.html

Answer (score 2):

First, logistic regression is **not** a classifier, it is about probability estimation.  Unbalanced classes per se is not a problem, unless there simple is not enough data in the class with few observations.  See for instance [Does an unbalanced sample matter when doing logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression)  for more information.

You do not need to make any changes in the estimation procedure, you simply change the loss function used for classification afterwards, if you need a classification.  That is, separate the estimation problem from using the estimated model to make decisions.