# Binary linear support vector machine classifier

Tags: classification, svm, dataset

I am trying to classify between two different categories a set of 2 dimensional points with a linear SVC.

To train the model I use a dataset with 64 samples from class A and 230 from class B. Is this allowed in a basic Support Vector Machine classification or should I try to balance the two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it "allowed"? Sure. Your model will focus more on class B than on class A, however. You can try assigning class weights to deal with this, so that the model will try harder to avoid misclassifying an A example than a B example, perhaps making the total weights of the classes equal; standard SVM software supports this easily.

The advice [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression) is applicable to SVMs as well as linear regression (though in SVMs, more than the intercept can change).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try to apply your suggestion in my analysis.