# Sequential Binary Imbalanced data classification with LSTM

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm building an LSTM sequential Binary Classification Model, the data is highly imbalanced like say Fraud detection case.

After building an LSTM model on Sequential Vectorised data, I'm getting a very low recall of 0.005.

```
# build LSTM layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM (100, dropout=0.2, input_shape=(time_steps, features)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=[Recall()])
print (model.summary())
history=model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_data=(test_X, test_Y), 
epochs=10,batch_size=64)
```

Please help me, with how to optimize the recall for this model.

Thank you

Comment: Optimizing recall is easy: every time, predict the class you want to recall. If you do this, you will never miss a case and will have perfect recall. If this approach is unacceptable (which I suspect it is), perhaps you can explain why.  // You might be interested in the links I posted in response to the answer be Baradrist. It turns out that metrics like acccuracy, precision, recall, sensitivity (same as recall), and specificity are surprisingly problematic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your training data, the "positive" class (since recall is the problem, I guess "fraud" is the "positive") is underrepresented and the algorithm has not enough data to pick up on this signal. There is even a valid easy strategy for it: It can get very high accuracy by only predicting the abundant class per default, since it will be wrong only very seldom.

What you can do now is to over- or undersample your data to make the classes artificially more equal. There are numerous techniques for that (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis)), plus you can also augment the positive samples that you use. There is also the option to weight your samples, meaning that positive samples get a very stronger influence on the error metric (scaled up relative to its reciprocal proportion in the data) assigned for backpropagation compared to the abundant class. For Keras this looks loke [this](https://androidkt.com/set-class-weight-for-imbalance-dataset-in-keras/). The alternative is to use another model (for outlier detection, sometimes autoencoders are employed ([here](https://datascience.oneoffcoder.com/autoencoder-anomaly.html#Detecting-outliers) and [here](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/2019/0378.pdf))).

Comment: Welcome to across Validated! Statisticians do not see class imbalance as such a problem and don’t particularly like accuracy as a metric. There is no need to use undersampling, oversampling, or artificial balancing to solve a non-problem.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/558942/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en