# What are some algorithms that are immune to class imbalance, and what makes them so?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415943/which-classification-algorithms-are-negatively-affected-by-class-imbalances) question is closely similar, however, the answer only speaks about Logistic Regression being one example.
I am interested in knowing if there are more algorithms that are not affected (at least lesser affected than other algorithms) by datasets that have class imbalance.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What issue(s) do you see class imbalance causing?

Comment: Thanks, Dave. The most common ones would be poor performance and bias.

Comment: Bias (what precisely do you mean by "poor performance"? An accuracy of 99.8% does not sound "poor", until one thinks about the class imbalance more deeply) arises not because of unsuitable algorithms, but because of evaluation metrics that reward it. [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)