# Imbalanced data to match reality with Random Forest?

Tags: random-forest, unbalanced-classes

I have a medical dataset which I am using select features to predict for 1 of 3 diseases. I have found that Random Forest works best for my dataset after testing out various combinations. The original data set was imbalanced towards one of the diseases, so I balanced the dataset with 33% of the dataset filled with each class. However, I know that in reality, roughly 70% of the population has disease 1, 20% disease 2, 10% disease 3.

I was wondering if I should be matching my dataset class frequencies to match the reality distribution of diseases or keep the classes balanced with Random Forest and why?

Comment: Good news! Class imbalance is not a problem!
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: In addition to what @Dave wrote, any method that removes valid data from the sample is statistically invalid and will also ruin predictions for future observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your classifier needs to be optimised for the operational class frequencies if you want it to perform well in operation.  However, this can be done *after* fitting the model if it produces an estimate of the a-posteriori probability of class membership.  Ideally, to make a decision, we need to know the probability that the input vector $x$ belongs to class $i$, using Bayes rule,

$p_t(C_i|x) = \frac{p_t(x|C_i)p_t(C_i)}{p_t(X)}$

where the $t$ subscript represents the conditions given in the training set.  Now if the training set is representative of operational conditions, then the output of the classifier will be a good estimate of the probability of class membership in operational conditions as well,i.e. $P_t(C_i|x) \approx P_o(C_i|x)$.

But what if this is not the case.  Say we have re-balanced the data set so that the classes are each represented by the same number of examples, but this was done in a way that did not affect the likelihoods, $P_t(x|C_i)$.  In this case all we need to do is to multiply by the ratio of the operational and training set prior probabilities, to give un-normalised operational class probabilities,

$q_o(C_i|x) = p_t(x|C_i)p_t(C_i)\times\frac{p_o(C_i)}{p_t(C_i)} = p_t(x|C_i)p_o(C_i) \approx p_o(x|C_i)p_o(C_i)$

The $o$ subscript indicates the operational conditions. We can then just re-normalise these probabilities so we have the probabilities of class membership calibrated for operational conditions,

$p_o(C_i|x) = \frac{q_o(C_i|x)}{\sum_{j}q_o(C_j|x)}$

If you have information about misclassification costs, these can also be factored in in a similar manner.

I don't completely agree with @Frank_Harrell about discarding samples (although I would generally advise against it, I wouldn't say it invalidates the exercise).  As long as $p_t(x|C_i)$ adequately characterises $p_o(x|C_i)$, it doesn't really matter which sub-sample of the data is used.  If we are trying to estimate the mean of a univariate Gaussian from 1,000,000 samples, then the estimate from 999,999 won't be invalid (and won't necessarily ruin predictions for future observations), just marginally less reliable.  There comes a point where the uncertainty is too small for our operational purposes, and it becomes reasonable to sub-sample the data for our model to be computationally feasible (or other such practical constraints).  But this only applies near assymptotically when you have a superfluosity of data, however I hardly ever find myself in that situation!

There are also applications where we *do* have to make a hard decision, for instance whether to perform a more sensitive test based on the outcome of a medical screening test.  So we do need to choose a threshold for some applications, and for those we need to consider class frequencies (in operation and in the training set) and often misclassification costs (it is generally worse for a screening test to give a false negative than a false positive).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I sort of understand what you mean (I am still new to statistics with ML). However, since I am using Random Forest instead of Naive Bayes classifier, would you recommend that I still match the class frequencies to match reality, even though it would unbalance the dataset?

Comment: @Gamer Class imbalance is not a problem. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @Dave it is not true that it is not a problem.  It is a problem for some classifiers and there are applications where you have to make a hard decision (rather than a propensity) and need to set a threshold.  It is much less of a problem that data science blogs will suggest, but it is an issue that needs to be attended to in some applications.

Comment: @Gamer, you can use the scheme I suggest for *any* classifier that outputs a probability (which can be done with RF).  Bayes' rule is a law of probability that isn't specific to Bayesian methods.  If your training set class frequencies are different to those in operational use, then this trick is essentially how to set a new classification threshold.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial. Thanks, I understand now. However, now I can not look at accuracy as a metric for the model, correct? Would it be better to see precision and recall for this model since class imbalance could skew accuracy?

Comment: @Gamer the metric you use depends on what is of practical importance for your particular application.  Accuracy is fine for problems with equal false-positive and false-negative costs and you have to make a decision (rather than wanting a ranking of examples).  For most medical problems false-positive and false-negative costs can be estimated, so use them to perform "minimum risk classification".

Comment: _"There comes a point where the uncertainty is too small for our operational purposes ..."_ I always thought that having low uncertainty is a good thing, be it uncertainty in out-of-sample predicted probabilities or in estimated model parameters. Am I missing anything here? I understand that the size of a large datasets may pose a computational challenge, but I don't see what this has to do with uncertainty.

Comment: @paperskilltrees if you have an infinite dataset, the uncertainty in estimating the model parameters will be zero.  That is indeed a good thing.  In practice you often don't need zero uncertainty in estimating the parameters, so using a finite dataset would be fine, and would be computationally cheaper.  The point I was making is that adding extra data is a matter of diminishing returns, so if you are already at the point where the parameter uncertainty is negligible, there is probably no real harm in downsampling the dataset.